# Symfony - Add class to form tag

Tags: forms, symfony

I know I can add classes to `<input>` fields in a form like this:

```
->add('foo', 'text', array('attr' => array('class' => 'foo-class'));
```

but how could I add a class to a `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For this, there's 2 solutions, either you do it in your controller or your view.

1) In your controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $data, ['attr' => ['class' => 'myClass']]);
```

2) In your view (Twig) :

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr' : { 'class': 'myClass' } }) }}
```

Comment: *The function "form_start" does not exist* when using the second option. Maybe due to I am using Symfony-2.1

Comment: Indeed, it seems like 'form_start' doesn't exists in SF 2.1.
http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/forms/twig_reference.html
  
If you can't upgrade your Symfony distribution, try to use to first solution, or just write your <form> tag manually.

Comment: Tried your first option with `createFormBuilder`, but doesn't seem to work. Solved writing the `<form>` tag manually. +1 anyway for your answer because probably there are not other ways to achieve it.

Comment: In fact, i made a mistake in solution 1, the third parameter was incorrect, and i've updated it. My bad

Answer (score 1):

In a form type class (working in Symfony 4+, not sure if in earlier), in `setDefaultOptions()`:

```
class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('bar')
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'App\Entity\Foo',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'custom-css-class']
        ]);
    }
}
```