# How to add class attribute in symfony form

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm looking to add some class attribute in my form using symfony form builder.

I have found how to do this for input and label, but not for the form tag.

```
$builder->add('label', TextType::class,
            [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'a'], // for input
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'b'], // for label
            ]
        );
```

But the render is the following:

```
<form method="POST">
      <label for="label" class="b">Label</label>
      <input type="text" class="a" name="label">
       <button type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

And i just want

```
<form method="POST" class="c">
```

I tried the following:

```
$builder->->setAttribute('class', 'c');
```

But it didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you do it in your builder, controller or your view.

Controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $data, array('attr' => array('class' => 'class')));
```

View (Twig) :

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr' : { 'class': 'class' } })
```

As Joe pointed out [source here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292073/symfony2-add-class-to-form-tag)

Comment: Probable source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292073/symfony2-add-class-to-form-tag

Comment: This solution is working.

Comment: I'm still wondering what $builder->->setAttribute('class', 'c'); is for?